# A blank bar appear at bottom when using translucent status bar in non-actionbar activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to use a Toolbar instead of an Actionbar with translucent status bar, but a thin bar(the same as the status bar in width) appears at bottom of the screen only if I'm using the NoAcitionbar theme.
And the color of the bar is the same as the 'windowBackgroud' I set. So I guess there's a margin or something.

I tried to reset all the margins but it didn't work.
And when I use the 'Android Device Monitor' in Android Studio to check the hierarchy of the UI the bar disappears, but re-disapear when I restart the app.

I'm using AppCompat v22 support lib and my Activity is AppCompat Activity.

I override this function in MainAcitivity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            // translucent status bar
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            // translucent navigation bar
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }
    }
}
```

In MainAcitvity there's only a fragment :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
android:name="org.bitoo.abit.ui.MainActivityFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mission_list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and the layout of fragment is here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_primary_color"
         tools:context="org.bitoo.abit.ui.DetailedMissionActivityFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_mission_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>


<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
    android:id="@+id/bt_add"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/accent_color"
    materialdesign:animate="false"
    materialdesign:iconDrawable="@drawable/ic_action_new" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Style of theme :

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/my_actionbar_style</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
  </style>

<style name="my_actionbar_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/dark_primary_color</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/my_actionbar_text_style</item>
</style>
<style name="my_actionbar_text_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You need to show us your layout and possible your layout overrides if any. A screenshot might be helpful too.

Comment: Just guessing here but did you run it on a lollipop device? Try running it on kitkat or adjust your code for lollipop. I found they behave differently. They do for me anyway.